# How to make an element with z-index=-1 receive click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I have a div with horizontal scroll with many images inside it. the div has an **1- inner shadow which should appear on it's children** but the **2-
 children should be able to receive pointer events**. Yet the **3- div should also be able to receive some pointer events to enable scrolling**. I've been searching and thinking for hours now. And I can't find any solution to achieve all of these three tasks at the same time. Does anyone have any idea on how I can get this done?

**Here is my code:**

```css
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  pointer-events:none;
}

div > img{
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img onclick="alert()" src="http://www.claireking.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/images.png"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: No way. That's what I was pointing out as a downside in my solution to your previous question. Pushing element to negative z-index makes him unreachable. You definitely need to find compromise between having shadow and padding on the block.

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh The problem is that the shaddow is for giving the feel that the things inside the div are under the scene like behind the page. And the padding solution can fix the problem for the top and bottom but it will look silly on the sides when some elements are being scrolled out of the div. Is it possible to achieve what I want with the div::before solution? I tried it once and it didn't work.

Comment: The :before solution will give you the same problem with not allowing to click on image. It produces pseudo-element on top of your div :( You need to look into different options here. Maybe wrap everything into another container with shadow on it and use negative margins for your inner div so it goes under the shadow.. I don't know. You need to play with this on your own.

Comment: Is it a problem to wrap the internal images in a separate tag ?

Comment: As long as my 3 requirements are satisfied no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that I am not understanding all the constraints, but perhaps you can wrap your internal images into another html element? for example:

```
  <div>
    <figure onclick="alert('hello')">
      <img src="http://www.claireking.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/images.png"></img>
    </figure>
    <figure onclick="alert('goodbye')">
      <img src="http://www.claireking.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/images.png"></img>
    </figure>
  </div>
```

and use the following css:

```
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  position: relative;
}

figure {
  /* just for this example: */
  height: 50%; 
  width: 150%;
  margin: 0;
}

div img{
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative;
}
```

You can play with this here: https://jsbin.com/kuzawemame/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I think that's what he's after. As a sidenote, that `figure{pointer-events:auto}` is not really needed, as that's the default value and you're not changing it in the parent anymore

Comment: Such a simple and brilliant answer!

Answer (score 1):

This almost does what you want. if you want the div not to move you have to set it's position to fixed and put it right where you want it to be on the window. I think it's better to use the third div for shadowing instead of pushing the elements you care about behind.

```css
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position:relative;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img onclick="alert()" src="http://www.claireking.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/images.png"></img>
  <img onclick="alert()" src="http://www.claireking.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/images.png"></img>
</div>
```