# PointerEvents on two elements a different zIndexes

Tags: javascript

I have an element a zIndex = 0 and another at zIndex = -1.
I know I can disable the first one using pointerEvents="none", But I want both to have pointer Events. How would I achive that? I thought on somehow delegating the events from zIndex =0 and triger them at zIndex =-1. Any Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an element with z-index=-1 receive click events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734733/how-to-make-an-element-with-z-index-1-receive-click-events)

Comment: I don't think so, The two elements I'm interested are in two different zIndexes